# Over(Partition by ) Column not being recognized. Invalid column

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute the following query:

```
SELECT 
    MH.MemberKey,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MH.MemberKey ORDER BY MH.MemberKey ASC) AS "NewRow",
    MH.FirstName,
    MH.LastName,
    MH.BirthDate,
    MH.AddressLine1,
    MH.AddressLine2,
    MH.AddressLine3,
    MH.City AS MemberCity, 
    MH.StateCode AS MemberState, 
    MH.ZipCode AS MemberZip 
FROM MembershipHistory MH 
WHERE NewRow = 1;
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
>   Invalid column name 'NewRow'.

I tried keeping `AS`, removing `AS`, removing `""`....nothing seems to work. It just wont recognize the column.

Answer (score 9):

The evaluation of the `row_number` function in the SELECT is done after the WHERE clause has been applied so the alias is not recognized, you can use a subquery to get the result:

```
select
    MH.MemberKey,
    NewRow,
    MH.FirstName,
    MH.LastName,
    MH.BirthDate,
    MH.AddressLine1,
    MH.AddressLine2,
    MH.AddressLine3,
    MH.City AS MemberCity, 
    MH.StateCode AS MemberState, 
    MH.ZipCode AS MemberZip 
from
(
    SELECT 
        MH.MemberKey,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MH.MemberKey ORDER BY MH.MemberKey ASC) AS NewRow,
        MH.FirstName,
        MH.LastName,
        MH.BirthDate,
        MH.AddressLine1,
        MH.AddressLine2,
        MH.AddressLine3,
        MH.City AS MemberCity, 
        MH.StateCode AS MemberState, 
        MH.ZipCode AS MemberZip 
    FROM MembershipHistory MH 
) MH
WHERE NewRow = 1;
```

In SQL Server the Logical Processinf Order of the SELECT Statement is (from [MSDN Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)):

> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be working. I've usually not seen such implementations of the over clause though. Strange.

Comment: @Sparsh curious, what implementations of the over clause *have* you seen?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Usually when you do row_number over(partition by....), the alias is used directly in the where clause to filter the data. I dont recollect ever having to use subqueries to use the alias.

Comment: @Sparsh can you show an example where this is possible? It has never been possible in any version of SQL Server that I have used, due precisely to the logical processing order of the `SELECT` statement that this answer lists. An alias created in the SELECT clause is not available in the WHERE clause, because the WHERE clause happens first, so the alias doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, you're right. I had used it to remove duplicates before, but the select was in a subquery. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @SparshParimoo usually when you think something is "strange" you're wrong. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to use a CTE:

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT MH.whatever, ROW_NUMBER() ... AS NewRow FROM dbo.table)
SELECT * FROM x WHERE NewRow = 1;
```